# Angularjs: connecting a set of buttons' output to a custom filter

Tags: arrays, angularjs, button, filter

I'm trying to write an app that lets you select a bunch of buttons each connected to a different array of restrictions for a search through another array. I already have the buttons connected to the array of possible restrictions and I'm using `ng-repeat` to create a button for each restriction from that array.

What I can't get is a way to get each button to add its restriction to an array for a filter to search through my database.

Comment: basically i think i need a way to get each button to output a string into a new array that then passes into the filter but i don't know how to do that

Comment: some code would be helpful

Comment: @Olga I agree.  A plunker or jsfiddle would be even better

Comment: Use ngClick to call a function which adds to the array. But please do set up a fiddle

Comment: quickly trying a possible solution. if it doesnt work i'll post some code here

Comment: a friend suggested trying something but wouldnt elaborate on how to apply it:   $scope.addDietaryRestriction = function(rest) {
        $scope.filter.restrictionTypes = $scope.filter.restrictionTypes || [];
        $scope.filter.restrictionTypes.push(rest);

Comment: small note, this is for an exercise i've been given to learn to use angular so my "database" of recipes is in angular as well

Comment: i have a plunker already set up if that would help?

Comment: @Andreis Gous no need to asking, just add link in question.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/gpnmby?p=info

Comment: the task is to use as much angularjs as possible

Comment: Are you posting using a mobile phone, Andries? If so, please don't - questions written in haste and without any regard to case and paragraphs are not very readable, and will create work for editors. Please see my recent edits.

Comment: Also, an excellent answer seems to have been offered below, but it is of concern that you have not replied to it, voted on it or accepted it, despite having seen it.

Comment: apologies. I've been away. I've voted on it now. It didn't quite solve my problem but it sent me on a path leading somewhere useful.

Answer (score 1):

I have forked your code, see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/uyr8eSHMe3sFf6Pzwf58?p=preview

I believe you didn't ask how to filter your recipes, but how to get the filter string to the controller?

**Controller**

```
  $scope.addDietaryRestriction = function (kind, restr) {
    console.log ($scope.filter);
    $scope.filter[kind] = restr;
    console.log ($scope.filter);
  }


  $scope.submit = function () {
    console.log ($scope.filter);
    console.log ($scope.filterConfig);
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h2>What courses?</h2>
      <button ng-repeat="course in filterConfig.courses" class="buttons" ng-click="addDietaryRestriction('course', course)">
    {{course}}</button>
    <br><br>
  </div>
```

Mind the two args in the `addDietaryRestriction()` call in `ng-click()`.

Personally, I'd also create the button-groups with an ng-repeat:

```
$scope.filterConfig = {
    dietaryRestrictions: {
      headline: "Dietary Restrictions:",
      values: [
          'Vegetarian',
          'Meat',
          'Nuts',
          'Wheat',
          'Dairy',
          'Kosher',
          'Halal'
        ]
    },
    courses: {
      headline: "What courses?:,
      values: [
        'starter',
        'main',
        'dessert'
        ]
    }, ....
```

and in the HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in filterConfig track by $index">
    <h2>{{value.headline}}</h2>
      <button ng-repeat="course in value.values" class="buttons" ng-click="addDietaryRestriction(key, course)">
    {{course}}</button>
    <br><br>
  </div>
```